# Is there a shorter way for if-else chains?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if (80 <= m <= 100):
    g = "A"
elif (70 <= m < 80):
    g = "B"
elif (60 <= m < 70):
    g = "C"
elif (50 <= m < 60):
    g = "D"
elif (m < 50):
    g = "U"
```

This is basically a grade measuring piece of code that takes in value m, meaning mark, and obtains grade g. Is there a shorter not necessarily more pythonic way for the same purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you can simplify by removing one of the bounds:

```
if m >= 80:
    g = "A"
elif m >= 70:
    g = "B"
elif m >= 60:
    g = "C"
elif m >= 50:
    g = "D"
else:  # default catch-all
    g = "U"
```

Secondly, you could capture the repetitive nature of the process by a loop (with the default case presenting an option for a for-else construct):

```
# iterator: ('A', 80) -> ('B', 70) -> ...
for grade, score in zip('ABCD', (80, 70, 60, 50)):
    if m >= score:
        g = grade
        break
else:  # executed if for-loop isn't 'break'-ed out of
    g = 'U'
```

Comment: Just a note, if you use the latter, please add a comment. I would spend far too much time trying to figure out what it did if I ran across this.

Comment: For general cases, this answer is correct for non-overlapping ranges. For overlapping ranges, see [Blender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47300654/1607442)

Comment: @jhpratt True. This is more of an academic exercise anyway. In production code, I'd go for the longer but explicit version of the OP or make bounds a more obvious data structure.

Comment: @Drop Not sure overlapping is a real issue in either version since both break aft.er the first hit

Comment: @schwobaseggl True, but what I wanted to say is that, if needed, in more general case (but not for this Q&A), dictionary solution can be used when in the original conditional tree, for some inputs, there is more than one correct branch. I guess that the branch taken is "unspecified" with `dict` and depends on order of tuples if `OrderedDict` is used. Solution with a list or tuple do not have this additional perk.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could do it this way, but it doesn't reduce the code much:

```
if m < 50:
    g = "U"
elif m < 60:
    g = "D"
elif m < 70:
    g = "C"
elif m < 80:
    g = "B"
else:
    g = 'A'
```

as a one liner (which is hard to read):

```
g = 'U' if m < 50 else "D" if m < 60 else "C" if m < 70 else "B" if m < 80 else "A"
```

Answer (score 4):

Shorter and less Pythonic? Definitely:

```
g='UUUUUDCBAAA'[int(m)//10]
```

Practically, I think your code conveys its intent well and is easy to read. Most other solutions will not be.

You could also do something like this:

```
GRADES = {
    'A': (80, float('+inf')),
    'B': (70,  80),
    'C': (60,  70),
    'D': (50,  60),
    'U': ( 0,  50),
}

def letter_grade(points):
    return next(g for g, (start, end) in GRADES.items() if start <= points < end)
```

I think it is straightforward and can be read the first time through <sup>(although I might be biased)</sup>.

Comment: This answer is correct even for overlapping ranges, but is more complicated. For the simpler solution for non-overlapping ranges, see [schwobaseggl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47300634/1607442)

Answer (score 2):

If `numpy` is acceptable there is `searchsorted`. Free bonus: it can handle an entire list of marks in one go:

```
import numpy as np

bnds = np.arange(50, 90, 10)
grades = np.array(list('UDCBA'))

marks = [52, 16, 50, 80, 69, 99]

result = grades[np.searchsorted(bnds, marks, side='right')]

print(result)

# ['D' 'U' 'D' 'A' 'C' 'A']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll exploit the single answer and touching ranges to reduce the number of comparisons, but also express the lookup table's structure using a tuple unpacking.

```
if m <= 100:
    g = next(grade for grade, belowscore in
           (('U',50), ('D',60), ('C',70), ('B',80), ('A',100+1))
           if m < belowscore)
```

This uses a generator expression to process a list of similar tests, shortcutting by reading only one result. This is inspired by [LISP's conditional operation](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/LispText/lisp-cond.html). Haskell has a similar thing in pattern guards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant, apart from the many already posted:

```
marks = [0, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100]
grades = ["U", "D", "C", "B", "A"]
g = [grades[i] for i in range(len(grades)) if ((m >= marks[i]) and (m < marks[i+1])) ][0]
```

The current student's marks are in `m` and the grade is put in `g`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change your code. It's readable and easy maintainable.

In general, skip "smart" one-liners, because compilers/interpreters can understand your code easily, but humans can have hard times to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas.cut`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bins = [-np.inf, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100]
labels=list('UDCBA')
print(pd.cut(pd.Series(m), bins=bins, labels=labels).iat[0])
# D
```

This is particularly applicable if you have more than one grade:

```
grades = np.random.randint(low=45, high=99, size=5)  # 5 grades

print(pd.cut(pd.Series(grades), bins=bins, labels=labels).tolist())
# ['U', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Dict,

```
m = int(input("Enter Marks:"))

a = {'A' : 80 <= m <= 100, 'B' : 70 <= m < 80, 'C' : 60 <= m < 70, 'D' : 50 <= m < 60, 'U' : m<50}

for key, value in a.items():
    if value == True:
        print(key)
```

gives

```
Enter Marks:35
U

[Program finished]
```

If you want to run this on multiple entries I would suggest switching to a function that returns the letter grade for what ever value you're passing in.